# Extend an existing attribute getter in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, model, methods, extensibility

i have a problem using acts_as_textiled and has_foreign_language plugins together.

**TextElement** my model in my app

```
class TextElement < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_foreign_language :value
    acts_as_textiled :value
```

**HasForeignLanguage**

```
def has_foreign_language(*args)
    args.each do |field|
        # Define the Getter
        define_method(field.to_s) do
        .
        .
        .
```

**ActsAsTextiled**

```
def acts_as_textiled(*attributes)
.
.
.
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    define_method(attribute) do |*type|
.
.
.
```

Both plugins use define_method and which ever way round i call the mixins in TextElement the latter overrides the getter previously defined.

Is there a way to save the existing getter and call that in the newly defined getter? similar to using super if they were inherited.

I have forked these plugins so all is fair game there.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can rewrite these two using alias_method_chain.

```
def some_class_method_that_overrides(*columns)
  columns.each do | c |
    overriden_name = if instance_methods.include?(c)
      alias_method_chain(c.to_sym, "extra")
      "#{c}_with_extra"
    else
      c
    end
    define_method(overriden_name) do ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you know what's going on here? the docs for alias_method_chain are very confusing.

Comment: Please google for alias_method_chain, there are loads of explanations on what it does

Answer (score 0):

You could try having one of the plugins decorate the attributes instead of redefining them. Something like (I'm extending Object here but you can extend whoever needs it):

```
class Object
  def decorate!(attr)
    method = self.method(attr)
    define_method(attr) do |value|
      result = method.call(value)
      yield(result)
    end
  end
end
```

So with decorate! in place you might try this in acts_as_textilized

```
def acts_as_textiled(*attributes)
.
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    self.decorate!(attribute) do |return_value_of_decorated_method|
    # decorate code here
```

Or something along those lines. Untested, you may have to tweak, but the basic idea is there I think.

Comment: Thanks Dave i'll give this a go tomorrow and let you know if it does the job.